# Date of Birth field in MM/dd/yyyy format date and automatically add '/' with Validation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Date of Birth** field in `MM/dd/yyyy` format date and when user enter `2 digit` than automatically add `'/'`

Validation should be made to make sure month is in between 01 to 12 and date is in between 01 to 31.

**month** empty ,**day** empty, **year** empty validation

Comment: Please ask your question in a question form. Use a question mark in the title. And put date formats between code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First Text Field

   ```
               TextFormField(
                 keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                 controller: birthDateInputController,
                 validator: Utils.birthDateValidator,
                 inputFormatters: [
                   LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                   FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
                   birthDateInput,
                 ],
               ),
   ```
2. Validation for input number **Utils.birthDateValidator**

   ```
   static String birthDateValidator(String value) {
   final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
   final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy');
   final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
   String str1 = value;
   List<String> str2 = str1.split('/');
   String month = str2.isNotEmpty ? str2[0] : '';
   String day = str2.length > 1 ? str2[1] : '';
   String year = str2.length > 2 ? str2[2] : '';
   if (value.isEmpty) {
     return 'BirthDate is Empty';
   } else if (int.parse(month) > 13) {
     return 'Month is invalid';
   } else if (int.parse(day) > 32) {
     return 'Day is invalid';
   } else if ((int.parse(year) > int.parse(formatted))) {
     return 'Year is invalid';
   } else if((int.parse(year) < 1920)){
     return 'Year is invalid';
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }
3. Automatically Add '/' after two digit. **birthDateInput**

> ```
>     class BirthTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
>   @override
>   TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
>       TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
>     if (oldValue.text.length >= newValue.text.length) {
>       return newValue;
>     }
>     var dateText = _addSeparator(newValue.text, '/');
>     return newValue.copyWith(
>         text: dateText, selection: updateCursorPosition(dateText));
>   }
>
>   String _addSeparator(String value, String separator) {
>     value = value.replaceAll('/', '');
>     var newString = '';
>     for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
>       newString += value[i];
>       if (i == 1) {
>         newString += separator;
>       }
>       if (i == 3) {
>         newString += separator;
>       }
>     }
>     return newString;
>   }
>
>   TextSelection updateCursorPosition(String text) {
>     return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi Jaimis. Thanks for sharing your solution but Validation for input doesnt work and throw error. Is there any possibility for you to test and share with us the updated solution. I appreciate your effort. Thanks in advance